# Uploading an image using LuaSocket

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm trying to upload an image using luaSocket.

Here is my Lua code:

```
function uploadFile(dir)
     local resp = {}
     local body,code,headers,status = http.request{
     url = "my_url",
     method = "POST",
     headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ["Content-Length"] = file_size
     },
     source = ltn12.source.file(io.open(dir),"rb"),
     sink = ltn12.sink.table(resp)
     }
     print(body,code,status)
     if headers then for k,v in pairs(headers) do print(k,v) end end end
```

My php code is:

```
<?php 
copy("php://input","test");
echo("OK"); 
?>
```

When I try to upload the image I don't get any error but body and status are nil, but code is "timeout".
But the script works fine if I try to upload a text file.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `file_size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `"rb"` as parameter to `ltn12.sink.file` instead of `io.open`. Change the statement to:

```
source = ltn12.source.file( io.open(dir,"rb") ),
```

Comment: That's interesting... while it is technically wrong, io.open(dir) *should* still return a proper file handle, and "rb" should be ignored unless the handle is nil. Maybe it's because it's a binary file under windows?