# Lua - Post multipart/form-data and a file via http.request

Tags: http, lua, paperless

I’m trying to use the [REST APi for Paperless-ngx](https://paperless-ngx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to upload documents to a http server, their instructions are as follows..

> POSTing documents
>
> The API provides a special endpoint for file uploads:
>
> /api/documents/post_document/
>
> POST a multipart form to this endpoint, where the form field document
> contains the  document that you want to upload to paperless. The
> filename is sanitized and then used  to store the document in a
> temporary directory, and the consumer will be instructed to  consume
> the document from there.
>
> The endpoint supports the following optional form fields:
>
> title: Specify a title that the consumer should use for the document.
>
> created: Specify a DateTime document was created (e.g. “2016-04-19” or “2016-04-19 06:15:00+02:00”).
>
> correspondent: Specify the ID of a correspondent that the consumer should use for the document.
>
> document_type: Similar to correspondent.
>
> tags: Similar to correspondent. Specify this multiple times to have multiple tags added to the document.
>
> The endpoint will immediately return “OK” if the document consumption
> process was started successfully. No additional status information
> about the consumption process itself is available, since that happens
> in a different process

While I’ve been able to achieve what I needed with curl (see below), I’d like to achieve the same result with Lua.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic Y2hyaXM62tgbsgjunotmeY2hyaXNob3N0aW5n" -F "title=Companies House File 10" -F "correspondent=12" -F "document=@/mnt/nas/10.pdf" http://192.168.102.134:8777/api/documents/post_document/
```

On the Lua side, I’ve tried various ways to get this to work, but all have been unsuccessful, at best it just times out and returns nil.

**Update:** I’ve progressed from a nil timeout, to a `400   table: 0x1593c00   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request {"document":["No file was submitted."]}` error message

Please could someone help ..

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
local mime = require("mime")
local lfs = require("lfs")

local username = "username"
local password = "password"

local httpendpoint = 'http://192.168.102.134:8777/api/documents/post_document/'
local filepath = "/mnt/nas/10.pdf"
local file = io.open(filepath, "rb")
local contents = file:read( "*a" )

-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

local boundary = "somerndstring"
local send = "--"..boundary..
            "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; "..
            "title='testdoc'; document="..filepath..
            --"\r\nContent-type: image/png"..
            "\r\n\r\n"..contents..
            "\r\n--"..boundary.."--\r\n";

-- Execute request (returns response body, response code, response header)

local resp = {}
local body, code, headers, status = http.request {
    url = httpendpoint,
    method = 'POST',
    headers = {
        -- ['Content-Length'] = lfs.attributes(filepath, 'size') + string.len(send),
        -- ["Content-Length"] = fileContent:len(), 
        -- ["Content-Length"] = string.len(fileContent), 
        ["Content-Length"] = lfs.attributes(filepath, 'size'),
        ['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data; boundary="..boundary,
        ["Authorization"] = "Basic " .. (mime.b64(username ..":" .. password)),
        --body = send
    },
    source = ltn12.source.file( io.open(filepath,"rb") ),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(resp)
}

print(body, code, headers, status)
print(table.concat(resp))

if headers then 
    for k,v in pairs(headers) do 
        print(k,v) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to a person on GitHub who helped me with this, and also has their own module to do it - https://github.com/catwell/lua-multipart-post .

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
local lfs = require "lfs"
http.TIMEOUT = 5

local function upload_file ( url, filename )
    local fileHandle = io.open( filename,"rb")
    local fileContent = fileHandle:read( "*a" )
    fileHandle:close()

    local boundary = 'abcd'

    local header_b = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="' .. filename .. '"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf'
    local header_c = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"\r\n\r\nCompanies House File'
    local header_d = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="correspondent"\r\n\r\n12'

    local MP_b = '--'..boundary..'\r\n'..header_b..'\r\n\r\n'..fileContent..'\r\n'
    local MP_c = '--'..boundary..'\r\n'..header_c..'\r\n'
    local MP_d = '--'..boundary..'\r\n'..header_d..'\r\n'

    local MPCombined = MP_b..MP_c..MP_d..'--'..boundary..'--\r\n'

    local   response_body = { }
    local   _, code = http.request {
            url = url ,
            method = "POST",
            headers = {    ["Content-Length"] =  MPCombined:len(),
                           ['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' .. boundary
                         },
            source = ltn12.source.string(MPCombined) ,
            sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body),
                }
     return code, table.concat(response_body)
end

 local rc,content = upload_file ('http://httpbin.org/post', '/mnt/nas/10.pdf' )
 print(rc,content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your `Content-Length` header value exceeds your actual content length you're trying to send.

That causes remote server to wait more data from you, which you don't provide. As a result, connection is being terminated by a timeout.

Check your code:

```lua
local size = lfs.attributes(filepath, 'size') + string.len(send)
```

`send` variable already contains your file contents, so you should not add your file content length twice by calling `lfs.attributes`.

Just try this:

```lua
local size = string.len(send)
```

You also do not use `send` variable anywhere in the actual request, which is another mistake.

Comment: Hi @marsgpl , good spot,  I can adjust the size, and thanks also for highlighting the omission of `send`, although I don’t know where to put it. ??  I tried adding it on the end of the http.request, but that didn’t work. I’m really stuck now.. Any ideas?

Comment: @nodecentral check similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103600/uploading-an-image-using-luasocket

try setting Content-Length to lfs.attributes(filepath, 'size')

Comment: Thanks @marsgpi, that’s helped, no further nil timeout response, but I do get a 400 error (see below)  I assume this points to sending the form and file part, which is the `send` section that I don’t know here that goes..? Any ideas ? FYI Code above updated ? `1     400   table: 0x1593c00   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request     
{"document":["No file was submitted."]}     
x-content-type-options     nosniff     
date     Sat, 22 Oct 2022 08:29:33 GMT     
cross-origin-opener-policy     same-origin     
referrer-policy   same-origin     
content-language   en-us     
content-length  39  ` etc.

Comment: @nodecentral try debug your requests with a wireshark. it'll be quite easy since you're using plain http. error literally says that you didn't submit a file, so check that you set `source` field correctly: it should look like `source = ltn12.source.file(io.open(filepath,"rb"))`

Comment: Hi @marsgpl, before setting up a machine to use wireshark, please could you help me with where the `send` part goes in the script. You’d highlighted that as a mistake earlier (which I agree) but I don’t know where it should go ?

Comment: @nodecentral you don't need to compose and use the `send` variable since you provide `source` field to the request

Comment: I’m so sorry @marsqpi, I’m just not getting this, it’s frustrating how such al (multi-part/form)  Curl command can be so straightforward , yet to do the same thing with Lua code is so difficult :-) . If it helps, if you use the code shared in the original post to httpbin.org it does not seem to show the file being sent vs the same details in the Curl command ?

Comment: You've spelled my name wrong. And I did not get your question. You are using a third party library that just implements sockets and http as lib's author wishes, it is not a standard way of using HTTP with Lua. I guess Diego Nehab does not maintain it anymore since it was removed from his page. Try reading lib's C code, it will help you to figure your problem out.

Comment: Thanks @marsgpi, I’m not familiar with `lib’s C code` or what that means, but I’ll take a look - thanks again for your patience with me. While I couldn't get this matter resolved in the way I hoped, I assumed the use of lua sockets was a pretty standard implementation/use case - but I’m always learning.. thanks again.. (We’ll leave this for now as unresolved, there is no standard / recommended way to do mutipart/form data submissions using Lua..